# How do I get an OIDC token from Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, openid-connect, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get an OIDC auth token using the Facebook Android SDK. I'm a newbie at this and am completely lost. The Facebook docs don't really provide code examples to assist with this, and I've scoured S.O. for a solution already.

I've tried some ideas with LoginManager and LoginConfiguration (snippets shown below), but at this point, I'm really just hoping that someone out there has implemented an OIDC Facebook auth flow and can share a tidbit of code with me.

Thanks!!

```
// do I need this somehow?
LoginManager.getInstance()(LoginConfiguration.OPENID);

// maybe use these somehow? 
String cv = lc.getCodeVerifier();
String non = lc.getNonce();

// didn't work
LoginManager.getInstance().loginWithConfiguration(this.getActivity(), lc);

// another attempt... didn't work
LoginManager.getInstance().logIn(this.getActivity(), lc);
```